# Basic Select Distinct issue

Tags: sql, db2-400

HI I have data like this:

```
  otord#       otusrn        ottrnc           ojhttn$          ottrnd
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   123           Joe          AAA              100.00         07/17/15
   123           Joe          BBB              100.00         07/16/15
```

I made this select: I really want to select distinct only on the order # and amt. But I want to show also the otusrn and code that is part of that distinct. So I want 123 and 100$ as the unique but 'tag along' the other columns is that what this will do?

```
SELECT DISTINCT otord#, 
                ohttn$, 
                ottrnd 
FROM replib.clspaytpl 
WHERE otusrn IN ('ANDON', 'SCH', 'JRU', 'BERT', 'TRA', 'LINA')
AND ottrnd >= 20140701
```

Comment: What if there are different  `otusrn` and `code` for a distinct `order #` and `amt`?  Which values do you want to show?

Comment: we can take the first one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve only the first detail record in a group joined with the header record you can use a syntax something like this:

```sql
WITH head (otord#, ojhttn$) as (
  SELECT DISTINCT otord#, ojhttn$
    FROM replib.clspaytpl
    WHERE otusrn in ('ANDON','SCH','JRU','BERT','TRA','LINA')
      AND ottrnd >= 20140701)
SELECT h.otord#, h.ojhttn$, d.otusrn, d.ottrnc, d.ottrnd
  FROM head h, 
       TABLE (SELECT * 
          FROM replib.clspaytpl
          WHERE otord# = h.otord# 
            AND ojhttn$ = h.ojhttn$
            AND otusrn in ('ANDON','SCH','JRU','BERT','TRA','LINA)
            AND ottrnd >= 20140701
          FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY) d
```

If you have a real header file that contains only one record per order/amount, you can use that instead of the CTE (Common Table Expression).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you do not specify what you want to do with your "tag along" columns, since they aren't unique you could have many results for the same record. You either have to include them in the distinct clause or take one  of the many possible record.

If you do not really care about the value of the "tag along" columns, you can use max() on them to return only the maximum value, but keep in mind you will loose data when they are different. So something like :

```
SELECT otord#, max(otusrn), max(ottrnc), ojhttn$, max(ottrnd)
FROM replib.clspaytpl 
WHERE otusrn IN ('ANDON', 'SCH', 'JRU', 'BERT', 'TRA', 'LINA')
AND ottrnd >= 20140701
group by otord#, ojhttn$
```

Comment: This will not necessarily give you a single physical record in the table, but rather a single `otord#, ojhttn$` with the maximum values for `otusrn`, `ottrnc`, and `ottrnd` independent of each other. That is, `otusrn`, `ottrnc`, and `ottrnd` could be returned from different records. Max does not return the first value, but the maximum value in the column for the group.

Comment: Correct, but in case such as this it's pretty much to be expected that the tag along values will not necessarily be coherent with the result. You might end up with a single line made up of info from 3 different record with the same otord# and ojhttn$. It depends on what you want to do with the tag along value